# Phonegap + Jquery mobile + JSON, append more results when scroll reach the end of listview

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, cordova, append

I looking for dynamic content to populate records which is callback by JSON, below script is working just excellent to pull out records from db, after some thought in mind if let say db table contained of more than 10000++ records, is that a way to limit the callback records to 20 until the scroll is reach the end in a listview data-role, then another 20 records will pull out from the end of list and so on.

PHP to query records from db:

```php
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT employeeNumber, firstName, email, jobTitle FROM employees ORDER BY firstName";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

Ajax to populate returned records:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// load JSON data
var output = $('#output');
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.loading('show'); },
    complete: function() { $.mobile.loading('hide'); },
    url: 'pool.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            var i = i + 1;
            var employee = '<li><a href="#indexPage"><img src="images/head.jpg" />'
            + '<h3>#' + i + " " + item.firstName + '</h3>'
            + '<p>' + item.employeeNumber + '<br>'
            + item.email + '<br>'
            + item.jobTitle + '</p></a></li>';

            output.append(employee);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        output.text('Error loading data!');
    }
});
});
```

Results will appended in here:

```html
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">   
        <ul data-role="listview" id="output" data-filter="true"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please kindly advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK. First you need to modify you SQL and ajax calls to support paging with LIMIT 0,20. Add to your SQL :

```
$sql = "SELECT employeeNumber, firstName, email, jobTitle FROM employees ORDER BY firstName LIMIT ". mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["page"]) . ",20";
```

This will limit the number of results to 20 counting from the passed page.

In javascript you have to pass the page (starting at 0) and store the current page.

```
url :'pool.php?page=' + page
```

and you have to start monitoring the scroll end of your element

```
$("#scroller").bind("scroll", function(evt){  
    var el = $(this).get(0);
    if (el.offsetHeight + el.scrollTop >= el.scrollHeight) {
         loadResults(++page);
    }
});
function loadResults(page) {
     // perform your ajax call
}
```

​

Here is a simple fiddle showing the scroll end detection  http://jsfiddle.net/nxtwrld/bH5Lb/1/

Comment: this can be for a lot of reasons. Do you use generic scrolling or something like iscroll? Where do you store you var page=0 context? Does the SQL return only 20 results using LIMIT 0,20 ?

Comment: yes it returned 20 results, my ajax call seem cannot trigger in a function when page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
</ul>



var timer    = setInterval(function () {
    scrollOK = true;
}, 100),
scrollOK = true,
count    = 20;
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if (scrollOK) {
    scrollOK = false;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= ($(document).height() - 100)) {
        //now load more list-items because the user is within 100px of the bottom of the page
        console.log('You Hit Bottom!');
        var out = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            out.push('<li>' + (count++) + '</li>');
        }
        $('ul').append(out.join('')).listview('refresh');
    }
}
});
```

Refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/knuTW/